# Warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I keep getting a lot of 'assignment from incompatible pointer type' warnings, and I haven't a clue as to why.

```
myPageFrame pageFrames[numOfFrames];
myPage pages[numOfPages];

//in a for loop
pageFrames[i].thePage = (myState == HOT ? (&pages[i]) : NULL);  // one of the offenders
```

I get the warning any time I try to do anything to `pageFrames[i].thePage`.

The structs in question are:

```
//algo_structs.h
typedef struct{

int pageNum;

} myPage;

typedef struct myPage{

struct myPage* thePage;
int loaded;
int lastRef;

} myPageFrame;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`myPage` and `struct myPage` are different types. You could make them the same type by changing the `struct` definition to:

```
typedef struct myPage {
    int pageNum;
} myPage;
```

or you could just use `myPage *` instead of `struct myPage *`.

Answer (score 0):

You've defined a type called `myPage`, but you then have a struct member of type `struct myPage`. You need to be consistent. Here's one way of fixing it:

```
typedef struct myPage{
    myPage* thePage;
    int loaded;
    int lastRef;
} myPageFrame;
```