# How to correctly implement queue with using Linked list

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, queue

I am currently working on my homework. In my program I had to use queue, so I wrote a queue with Linked list. But it doesn't seem to like my syntax.

So I have struct

```
  typedef struct Node{
  pthread_t thread;
  int threadID;
  int securityMode;  // nTS = 1, S = 2, U = 3
  //int cluseterHalf;  //either 1st or 2nd
  struct NODE *next;
  int executionTime;
  int isLast;
}NODE;
typedef NODE *Link;
```

And this is where I tried to do Enqueue.

```
void Enqueue(Link node, Link *Queue){
  Link previous = NULL;
  Link current = *Queue;
  while (current->isLast){
    previous = current;
    current = current->next;
  }
  if(previous == NULL){
    node->next = current;
    *Queue = node;
  }
  else{
    previous->next = node;
    node->next = current;
  }
}
```

I tried to change my code a bit, but I am getting this error.

```
Cluster.c:162:13: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
[enabled by default]
     current = current->next;
             ^
Cluster.c:165:16: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
     node->next = current;
                ^
Cluster.c:169:20: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
     previous->next = node;
                    ^
Cluster.c:170:16: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
     node->next = current;
```

I have tried to look at some stackoverflow questions similar to mine. 
1)[Question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20342324/warning-assignment-from-incompatible-pointer-type)

So I made many logical and non-logical attempts. I tried to write 
node->next = &current since next is a pointer and it will get the address value. But it didn't work :( 
I also tried to do oposit *(node->next) = current

I finally found the correct option for me, but I am not sure If that's what I wanted. I was thinking that I had to have struct NODE *next
but If I change NODE *next to NODE next than I don't get those errors. But I get different one:

```
Cluster.c:25:15: error: field ‘next’ has incomplete type
   struct NODE next;
```

Can you please tell me how to fix this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: this line: 'typedef NODE *Link;' is a bad idea as it produced a typedef of a typedef    
 
when typedef'ing a pointer, it is much better coding practice to include some kind of indication in the new typedef name as to what it points to and that it is a pointer. suggest "typedef NODE *pNode'  and there is never any valid reason to typedef a struct definition.  just use 'struct Node'  when ever needed and remove the typedef modifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `struct NODE *next;` to `struct Node *next;` in definiton of your structure

**EDIT:**

Looking more on the code, I think you have some problems at the pointer assignments. For example, I think that `Link current = *Queue;` will assign only data of `Queue`, not address, therefore you cannot access the "inside". Same problem could be with previous.

Also, I dont really understand what's the purpose of `Link`, you could go with just `NODE`

Comment: Thanks! changing NODE to Node helped. but can u explain a bit why NODE doesn't work and Node does? Cause I thought they were the same thing.

Comment: I think u are wrong on *Queue. Because Queue is already a pointer (Link), so when I pass Queue as argument I pass the pointer to array of Nodes. So   I have to add * to make Link current = to Queue. Without * I get error.

Comment: Because you define name of the structure, NODE, at the very end of the definiton and meanwhile, inside the structure, you use Node as some sort of alias.

Comment: ooh so by that time NODE doesn't really exist right?

Comment: Exactly, you could say that until you reach NODE, only Node exists. Then it's replaced.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I got lucky too :)

Answer (score 1):

the posted code will present lots of problems when being maintained.  Also the code contains several cluttered areas that make understanding/debugging unnecessarily difficult.  Meaningful variable names also greatly helps.  Suggest:

```
struct Node
{
    pthread_t thread;
    int threadID;
    int securityMode;  // nTS = 1, S = 2, U = 3
    //int cluseterHalf;  //either 1st or 2nd
    struct Node *next;
    int executionTime;
    // notice removal of unneeded field isLast
};


void Enqueue(struct Node *newNode, struct Node **Queue)
{
    struct Node *current = *Queue;

    newNode->next = NULL;

    if(NULL == current)
    { // then handle special case of empty linked list
        *Queue = newNode;
    }

    else
    { // else, some nodes already in linked list
        // loop to end of linked list
        while (NULL != current->next)
        {
            // step to next node in linked list
            current = current->next;
        } // end while

        // add node to end of linked list
        current->next = newNode;
    } // end if
} // end function: Enqueue
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you please explain why I should put struct in paramiters in Enqueue? I mean Why should I have struct Node *newNode instead of Node *newNode?