# Why doesn't the printf function print the value of the list I want it to print?

Tags: c, list, printf

I can't manage to print the data value of the first node. Could someone show me what I'm doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct S_node{

  int data;
  struct S_node *next;

} node;


int main () {

  node* first; 

  first->data = 7;
  first->next = NULL;

  printf("\nData: %d", first->data);

}
```

I updated my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct S_node{

  int data;
  struct S_node *next;

} node;

void PrintList(node* start);

int main () {

  node* first = malloc(sizeof(node));
  node* second = malloc(sizeof(node));
  node* third = malloc(sizeof(node));

  first->data = 7;
  first->next = second;

  second->data = 6;
  second->next = third;

  third->data = 5;
  third->next = NULL;

  PrintList(first);

  free(first);
  free(second);
  free(third);
}

void PrintList(node* start) {

node* currentNode = start;
while(currentNode =! NULL) {
    printf("Data: %d", currentNode->data);
    currentNode = currentNode->next;
}
}
```

I'm trying to print the data from the first to the last node, still getting the "assignment from incompatible pointer type" warning when doing

```
first->next = second;
```

and

```
second->next = third;
```

When i run the program, nothing gets printed.

Comment: `first` hasn't been assigned (or initialized with) a correct value.

Comment: Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: The only problem in the revised code is the line `while(currentNode =! NULL) {` where you're assigning `1` (`!NULL`) to `currentNode` and getting a type mismatch (integer assigned to pointer, of different size on my 64-bit machine).  That is presumably meant to be: `while(currentNode != NULL) {`.    When fixed and run, it produces coherent output, but you should include newlines somewhere in the printing (probably at the end of the `printf()` format string in `PrintList()`).

Answer (score 1):

when you got a pointer like

```
node* first
```

You should specialize this pointer point to which address.
by `malloc` we can got dynamic space in memory and assign the address to pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct S_node {

    int data;
    struct S_node *next;

} node;


int main() {

    node* first = malloc(sizeof(node));

    first->data = 7;
    first->next = NULL;

    printf("\nData: %d", first->data);

}
```

Comment: Thank you, that made it work, untill i decided to allocate memory for a second node, then when I changed first->next = second; gave me a warning "assignment from incompatible pointer type". What do i have to do to make the next variable of the first node to point to the second node?

Comment: your welcome,That was difference between struct S_node *next and node* first.  check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20342324/warning-assignment-from-incompatible-pointer-type

Answer (score 0):

```
int main () {

  node* first = NULL;           // Be Explicit that the pointer is not yet valid.
  first = malloc(sizeof(node)); // Now there is memory attached to the pointer.

  first->data = 7;
  first->next = NULL;

  printf("\nData: %d", first->data);

  free(first);  // Release the memory when done.
  first = NULL; // Prevent accidental re-use of free'd memory

}
```

Comment: This code-only answer would benefit greatly fromm some explanation.

Comment: Read the comments:  The explanation is in the comments.

Comment: Use: `node *first = malloc(sizeof(*first));` or thereabouts.  There's no virtue in initializing to NULL only to overwrite it one line later with the call to `malloc()`.

Comment: I'm emphasizing that pointers can be invalid or NULL, and can later be changed to point to valid memory.  Yes, it can be done shorter, but that skips the concept that a pointer is not useful until it is actually set to something.

Comment: Comments are not a part of the answer. They are to ask for clarifications or point out errors.

Comment: @n.m. — I think you and abelenky are talking at cross-purposes.  The `// C99` comments in the code in the answer are part of the answer.  The comments below the answer (like the one I'm typing) are not part of the answer.  I'm not clear why you think that comments in the code in the answer are not part of the answer.  I'd prefer running text commentary too, but completely dissing the comments in the code of the answer isn't appropriate.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yeah misunderstood "comments" completely, sorry. Comments in the code are OK but IMO still too terse to be useful in this case.